# domain name parsing

Tags: c, regex, parsing

I have this code:

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>

        int main()
        {
         char buf[255];
         char buf2[255];
         char myhost[255] = "subdomain.domain.com";

         char *pch;
         int token_counter = 0;

         memset(buf, 0, 255);
         memset(buf2, 0, 255);
         pch = strtok(myhost, ".");
         while (pch != NULL)
           {
                pch = strtok(NULL, ".");
                if (pch == NULL)
                   {
                        memset(buf, 0, 255);
                        strncpy(buf, buf2, strlen(buf2) - 1);
                        break;
                   }
                token_counter++;
                strcat(buf2, pch);
                strcat(buf2, ".");
           }
         printf("Domain: %s\n", buf);
         return 0;
        }
```

this is working fine if myhost is defined as subdomain.domain.com but if it's domain.com it shows "com" as final result.

***How can I make it detect correctly if it's a subdomain or a domain? Maybe if I include a list of known tlds?***

Comment: What is this to do with regex? You are just tokenising on a character

Comment: I used to do this with regex in other programming languages and I thought there is something similar in c

Comment: there is but that is not what your question asks

Comment: Count tokens.  How do you want to deal with `a.b.c.d.e.f.uk`?

Comment: I already thought about this and a list with valid tlds which includes co.uk and so on, would do it. My problem is that I don't know how to implement it in C

Comment: You wouldn't be the first, Google Webmaster Tools used to get confused by those domains, they may still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` is overkill and `strcat` is wasteful.  If you just want to print everything past the nth `.`, use `strchr` or just examine the string to find the nth `.`. If so desired, count from the end of the string.

Let me explain why `strcat` is a waste of time here.  Consider:

```
const char *name = "foo.bar.baz.qux.net";
printf( "%s\n", name + 8 );
```

If you want to print "baz.qux.net", you do not need to copy that string into a new buffer since you already have a pointer to the first character of the desired string.  Use what you have.  All you need to do is find a pointer to the desired `.` in the string, and then do `printf( "%s\n", dot + 1 )` or `puts( dot + 1 )`.  (`puts` is better here, but you are probably more familiar with `printf`)

Comment: your arguments are very useful and I will consider them as soon as I get an idea about how to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

To determine if it is a subdomain count the number of tokens,separated by periods, in the host name. And as pointed out in a comment above this doesn't take things like foo.on.ca into account.

Comment: I'd love to do that but I'm kinda n00b in native c. Just trying to modify something. C is not my current programming language

Comment: Your token_counter variable has the count in it.